# playing links of music on my own video player

Tags: javascript, html

i have a problem, i have a player in my website and the music i want to play is just a link of music, and i want to play it in my own player. i need some idea about this...

thanks you!..

Answer (score 0):

My favorite HTML5 solution for audio right now is this project: http://kolber.github.com/audiojs/

It "fixes" the users browser so the HTML5 <audio /> tag works no matter which browser they are using (IE, FF, Safari, etc). Then with just a sprinkling of JS you can just add something like this to your page:

```
<audio src="/mp3/juicy.mp3" preload="auto" />
```

Check out the project page, the setup shouldn't take more than 5-10 minutes.

Apparently there is also a videojs library to run HTML5 video. Its slightly more complicated but if you combine the two, it should give you all the power you need.

http://videojs.com/#getting-started

Comment: You may want to edit your question and add that as a requirement. Obvious audiojs isn't going to work for video.